# In Postgresql 10.8,how to change the char type field to json type and then get the number in the json string?

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-10

The Postgresql Version is 10.8

This is sql:

```sql
update nt_order set common_field='{"bind_channel":"company","bind_status":"binding","version":1234}' where id=1 and (common_field is null or (common_field::json->>'version')::bigint is null or (common_field::json->>'version')::bigint < 12345);
```

When executing this sql, there is an error:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  The input string ended unexpectedly.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1
```

If the Postgresql version is 9.5,there is no problem executing the above sql.

So how to solve this problem in Postgresql 10.8?

Comment: Simple. There is a value in `common_field` that is not a valid JSON.

Comment: Well this: `'{"bind_channel":"company","bind_status":"binding","version":1234}'` is correct input. Is it the actual value that got rejected? What is the type definition for the `common_field`?

Comment: @Adrian Klaver The type definition for the ```common_field``` is ```character varying```.I can't define it as ```json``` because of the development framework.

Comment: What development framework would that be? Then the issue is in `common_field::json->> 'some_field'`, where `common_field` cannot be cast to `json` due it not being a properly formed JSON string.

Comment: @Adrian Klaver The development framework is ```openerp 7```.Its ```ORM``` does not support defining the field as a json type.If I do not change the field type, is there any other way to complete the effect of the sql execution?I expect only one SQL can be complete it.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to ask. In any case I would add a better explanation, with example, as update to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the DETAIL and CONTEXT, I would say you have the empty string in your field for some row.  This cannot be cast to json, not even in version 9.5, so your 9.5 server must have different data in it.

Presumably you want to do the same thing for '' as you do for NULL, so just add that test into your OR list.

Comment: Well,regardless of whether ```common_field``` is null or not null, the sql can be executed successfully in Postgresql 9.5, but not in Postgresql 10.8.